# Inputting values in a website and receiving an output value from a specific cell in a google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a platform for my school and I want it to include a feature which lets student find out how many "passport" points they have.
I'm trying to have an *input* and *button* command which allows students to input their Student ID (a 9-digit number), and it should return them the points that correspond with their id-number. I have a master google spreadsheet, and it contains some of the data. Here's how it looks.

[Image of Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hTDj.png)

For example, if someone were to input 000123456 and the website would return 12. Could someone guide me in terms of how I could link my website with a google spreadsheet? I'd really appreciate any help. Thank You!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your goal from your image and your question. Can you provide your current script and the current issue of your script, and also, can you provide the sample output situation as an image?

Comment: If someone inputs 000123456 (which matches the cell A3 in the excel document), I would like to get an output of 12 (which is in cell P3). Or if someone inputs 000123457 (A4) I I would like to get an output of 8 (P4 in excel). But this input is supposed to be a user input in a website.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. About `inputs` of `If someone inputs 000123456`, I cannot still imagine your goal. From your tags of `javascript, php, html, css, google-sheets`, you don't want to use the custom dialog and sidebar and Web Apps? Can you provide the sample output situation as an image?

Answer (score 0):

Your goal can be easily reached by developing a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) that asks for an input and returns the associated value.
After you [deploy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app) the web app, you could share the link or embed it in your webpage. [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles) you can read some examples.